# This might be interesting. The ring $R[x_1, \dots]$ (Non-specific)

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, polynomials

Let $R$ be a commutative ring and define $\mathcal{R} = R \oplus \bigoplus_{i=1}^{\infty} x_i R[x_1, \dots, x_i]$.  Then $\mathcal{R}$ is an $R$-algebra of polynomials in any finite number of variables.  Addition and multiplication are done by formally multiplying the finite polynomials to get a polynomial in a larger number of variables.

Now define an equivalence relation on $\mathcal{R}$ to be $f = g$ iff they're each on the same number of variables and for the variable vector $x, \ f(x) = g(\sigma x)$ for some variable replacement function $\sigma$.  So for instance $f(x_1, x_2 ) = x_1 x_2 + x_1^2 \equiv g(x_3, x_1) = x_3 x_1 + x_3^2$.  Let $\mathcal{S}$ be the set of equivalence classes on $\mathcal{R}$.  It forms an $R$-algebra with addition defined as, for class representatives $f,g$, sharing no variables, $h(x, y) := f(x) + g(y)$, i.e. the equivalence class containing $h$.  Define multiplication similarly and scalar mul in the natural way.

Define $R^{\infty}$ to be the set of all $n$-tuples for $n \geq 1$, of elements of $R$. Define addition by first left-aligning the two tuples and adding componentwise.  For a mismatch in length, append to the shorter vector enough zeros on the right just for the computation.  Define scalar multiplication in the natural way.  Then we have an $R$-module on which an additional operation present called concatenation.  Given two tuples $u = (u_1, \dots, u_n), \ v = (v_1, \dots, v_m)$ define $u \cdot v = (u_1, \dots, u_n, v_1, \dots, v_m)$.

Now evaluating $\tilde{f} \in \mathcal{S}$ we say that $\tilde{f}(x) = a$ iff $f(x)$ is defined and equals $a$ for some $f \in \tilde{f}$.

Now with $\mathcal{S}$ as the ring of polynomials, define an algebraic subset of $R^{\infty}$ to be $Z(J)$ for the ideal $J \subset \mathcal{S}$, i.e. $Z(J) = \{ x \in R^{\infty} : (f^k)(x)$ is defined and $(f^k)(\tau x) = 0$ for some $k \geq 1$ and for some index permutation $\tau: (x_1, \dots, x_n) \mapsto (x_{\tau(1)}, \dots, x_{\tau(n)})$, for all $f \in J \}$.  Notice that this is weaker than the usual algebraic set, so the sets should be bigger.  Also notice that $Z(f)$ is now closed under concatenation.

Has anyone studied algebraic geometry in this fashion?

**Edit** the definition of $Z(J)$ can be edit equivalently to $Z(J) = \{ x \in R^{\infty} : (f^k)(x)$ is defined and equals $0$ for some $k \geq 1$, for all $f\in J \}$ since $f$ contains all permutations of variables. Here's a more detailed proof:

Since the first version is weaker we have that $Z_1(J) \supset Z_2(J)$, where $Z_i$ is version $i$.    So let $x \in Z_1(J)$, then $(f^k)(\tau x) = 0$ for some $k \geq 1$ and index perm $\tau$.  But by our note on how to evaluate $f \in \mathcal{S}$, we have that $(f^k)(\tau x) = (f^k)(x)$ since $\tau$ is an index permutation but in particular a variable replacement function.

Comment: I'm wondering, wouldn't an equivalent, but easier to work with, definition of $R^{\infty}$ be to define it to be all sequences in $R$ with all but finitely many $0$ terms? Then the addition and multiplication would naturally be component-wise, and the concatenation operation can just be defined for $x=(x_{1},\ldots,x_{m},0,\ldots)$ and $y=(y_{1},\ldots,y_{n},0,\ldots)$ by taking $x\cdot y = x + S_{m+1}\left(y\right)$ when $S_{k}$ shifts a sequence by $k$ components, padding with $0$'s.

Comment: Your concatenation is wrong though.  You concatenate to the last nonzero $x_m$, but my concatenation is done after the last string of zeros since it's all within a vector.  So the boundary of the vector is implicitly kept in my version.  In yours you'd have to work with $\ell(x)$ the number of components of $x$ which isn't well-defined.

Comment: I don't see where the concatenation doesn't work. The $x_{m}$ component isn't necessarily nonzero, it's just the last component before the definitely-zero components in my representation of your $m$-tuple as the first $m$ components of a sequence of elements in $R$.

Comment: Also, are you sure that your definition of $R^{\infty}$ is an $R$-module? Unless you have an equivalence relation to fix this, you have $a_{1} = \left(0\right)$, $a_{2}=\left(0,0\right)$, and $b=\left(1,1\right)$ give $a_{1}+b=\left(1,1\right)=a_{2}+b$, but $a_{1}\neq a_{2}$, which means that $\left(R^{\infty},+\right)$ is not a group since it violates right cancellation.

Comment: Oh so we need to equate all $n$-tuples that are equal upto different number of last sequence of zeros.

Comment: Yeah, but then you'll see that there's an obvious bijection from your $R^{\infty}$ modulo the equivalence relation to my $R^{\infty}$ with concatenation then being what I defined before. That's why I thought that my definition was easier to work with, since you reduce concatenation to addition with a right-shift operator wedged in between.

Comment: Note that $\mathcal{R}$ is just the usual polynomial ring $R[x_1,x_2,\dotsc]$.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg yes, I haven't figured out a use for decomposition into a direct product of ideals yet.